# contact form not sending email to my specific address

Tags: forms, contacts

I have a php contact form on my website. It sends me email on my normal address. But when I put in the desired mail recipient address in the 'to' section. I do not get any email. What could be the issue??

```html
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = ' Contact Form'; 
  $to = ''; 
  $subject = 'Message from Website contact page ';
  
  $body ="From: $name\n Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
  // Check if name has been entered
  if (!$_POST['name']) {
   $errName = 'Please enter your name';
  }
  
  if (!$_POST['number']) {
   $errNumber = 'Please enter your mobile number';
  }
  
  // Check if email has been entered and is valid
  if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
  }
  
  //Check if message has been entered
  if (!$_POST['message']) {
   $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
  }
  
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errNumber && !$errEmail && !$errMessage ) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will get in touch with you soon.</div>';
 } else {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
 }
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: so you are not getting mail in the desired mail inbox? Do you checked it in newly given mail account's inbox/spam

Comment: Yes I checked. Getting nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

can you check this:

```
$to = "desiredmailID@example.com, yourmailID@example.com";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: noreply@example.com" . "\r\n";
  // Check if name has been entered
  $errName = '';
  if ($_POST['name'] == '') {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
  }
  //Other validation messages here...

  // If there are no errors, send the email
  if ($errName == '' && $errNumber == '' && $errEmail == '' && $errMessage == '' ) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
      $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will get in touch with you soon.</div>';
    } else {
      $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: tried this. still doesn't work. Can it be some problem of my business email hosting provider?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so sure about that. For other mail ID's, it is working right?

Comment: yes. it is working for all the rest. my website is hosted on one server and the email hosting is dome on another. could this be the cause of trouble ? is my website not being able to communicate with the email host?